# pySVG css links

Tags: python, svg

I'm trying to figure out pySVG, having trouble understanding how to link to an external CSS file, does pySVG handle this?  Looking over the documentation, the style seems to be hard coded in most of the examples.

Further, I'd love to add an 'onclick' to change the CSS reference, so, a heat map (for example) could link to a default CSS which styles elements for one set of data, but then the css can be changed to style the elements for a different set of data. I'm not sure whether this requires javascript, or if svg can handle it in the xml.

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure how pySVG does things, but you can add an external CSS to an SVG you've created by adding:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="CSS_filename.css" ?>
```

It should be the very first line of the file, i.e. before the DOCTYPE declaration.

As for the onclick changes, you can have an element like this:

```
<circle class="class1"
        cx="10" cy="10" r="4"
        onclick="evt.target.setAttributeNS(null, 'class', 'class2')"/>
```

This will change the class of the circle from `class1` to `class2` when you click on it (changing it back would be more complicate and probably require javascript or EMCAScript within the SVG itself). I'm not sure how pySVG handles these things, but if you can add arbitrary attributes to elements then you can add the onclick event.

Comment: maybe i should have been more specific, i'm working to create a chloropeth map, able to handle an arbitrary number of data sets, i.e. unemployment figures by county for ten years, able to change element styles (thousands of elements) to its value in any of the ten periods

Comment: OK, that will require Javascript, EMCAScript. I've actually started to write a tutorial about how to do something similar (http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/introduction-svg-scripting-interactive-map), but haven't got to the bit about colouring the map. I'll try to write it this week.